# Esper AMQPSource not receiving events

Tags: amqp, esper, epl, nesper

I'm trying to use the AMQPSource and I'm getting the error describe below, also imports are not working in EPL module. In advance, I test adding full package name to DistanceEvent (events.DistanceEvent and does not work).

To sending a message i'm using the publish Rabbitmq webadmin queue option with  the next payload:
{"distance":33}

Could anyone help me?

[image: Error]

[image: EPL Module]

[image: Deploying EPL Module]

[image: Event definition]

[image: Dataflow instance]

[image: Sender]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "IO-error deserializing object" is the reason you are not seeing data.
The "AMQPToObjectCollectorSerializable" expects the AMQP message to carry a valid JVM-serialized object however the "invalid header" means that the message content cannot be read by the JVM. Check the sender making sure it produces a AMQP message with a JVM-serialized object or may use replace "AMQPToObjectCollectorSerializable" with a deserializer that can understand your message. The code for "AMQPToObjectCollectorSerializable" can be found in Github if your are not sure how it deserializes.

Comment: Could you check the new edit? This is the sender. 
It is supposed to be serialized, Isn't it'??

Comment: The sender looks like its sending a String message that contains a Json text. Thats not the same as a JVM-serialized objects. You will need to write a your own deserializer (interface AMQPToObjectCollector) that parses the Json and send events into Esper.